# Looking to add High and Low toolstips to xlStockOHLC candlestick charts in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Running on Windows.
I see plenty of examples on SO but they're all in JS.
I am using VBA and creating my candlestick chart with the following:

```
    OHLCChartObject.name = OHLCChartName
        With OHLCChartObject.Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=getOHLCChartSource
        .ChartType = xlStockOHLC
        .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = ""
        .HasLegend = False
        With .ChartGroups(1)
            .UpBars.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            .DownBars.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**Is there any way to add tooltips to show the actual Open/High/Low/Close values?**

Answer (score 2):

May try Some workaround this.

[image]

Instead of changing Toolstip, in test it is used to show values in a Shape "Rectangle 2" embedded in the chart itself. However it could be easily modified to show the results along with the title or `Datalabel` of the point with mouse move.

Create a class module named `XChart` with Chart Events

Class module Code

Edited: added additional functionality of modifying data labels.

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents Ohlc As Chart
Public Arr1 As Variant, Arr2 As Variant, Arr3 As Variant, Arr4 As Variant
Private Sub Ohlc_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
Dim IDNum As Long, a As Long, b As Long
Dim i As Long, txt As String, ht As Long, txt2 As String
Ohlc.GetChartElement x, y, IDNum, a, b

If IDNum <> xlSeries Then
'Finding XlSeries in OHLC chart is little difficult
'So try all Y values correspoding to X in the chart to find XlSeries
'However this compromise performace
ht = Ohlc.Parent.Height
    For y = 1 To ht
    Ohlc.GetChartElement x, y, IDNum, a, b   'c, d
    If IDNum = xlSeries Then Exit For
    Next
End If

If IDNum = xlSeries Then
' For Test purpose, May delete next 5 lines
ActiveSheet.Range("L1").Value = x
ActiveSheet.Range("L2").Value = y
ActiveSheet.Range("L3").Value = IDNum
ActiveSheet.Range("L4").Value = a
ActiveSheet.Range("L5").Value = b
    If b > 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("M1").Value = Arr1(b)  ' For Test purpose, may delete
    txt = "Open: " & Arr1(b) & " High: " & Arr2(b) & vbCrLf & _
            "Low: " & Arr3(b) & " Close: " & Arr4(b)
    txt2 = "O: " & Arr1(b) & " H: " & Arr2(b) & _
            " L: " & Arr3(b) & " C: " & Arr4(b)
    Ohlc.Shapes("Rectangle 2").TextEffect.Text = txt

       For i = 1 To Ohlc.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
       With Ohlc.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i)
            If i = b Then
            .HasDataLabel = True
            .DataLabel.Text = txt2
            Else
            .HasDataLabel = False
            End If
       End With
       Next
    End If
End If
End Sub
Public Sub Storevalues()
Arr1 = Ohlc.SeriesCollection(1).Values
Arr2 = Ohlc.SeriesCollection(2).Values
Arr3 = Ohlc.SeriesCollection(3).Values
Arr4 = Ohlc.SeriesCollection(4).Values
End Sub
```

Next in the VBA Code in standard module where Chart was created or in some other event / procedure, set the Chart as new `XChart`. For test an already existing chart is used. it may also be used at workbook open event.

```
Public XOhlc As New XChart
Sub initChart()
Dim Ch As Chart
'Modify the line to your requirement
Set Ch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart
Set XOhlc.Ohlc = Ch
XOhlc.Storevalues
End Sub
```

All the Sheet,Chart, Shape etc names may please be modified to requirement.

Comment: Thank you. I love the idea... and used your test below is integrated into my code but the chart object shows up as empty. 'Not sure why... :(

Comment: Not clear about "chart object shows up as empty". If the chart is created with VBA, then may please set it as `XChart` only after completion  of Chart creation. May please add more details about the problem.

Comment: Nice work!!  There is no need to iterate over the chart elements.  You should rename `a` to SeriesIndexand `b` to `PointIndex`.  They can be accessed directly using `
Ohlc.SeriesCollection(SeriesIndex).Points(PointIndex)`.  See [Chart.GetChartElement method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.getchartelement?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm149161)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue).

Comment: Actual `Arg1` and `Arg2` would be better names for the parameters because their usage changes depending on the chart element id assigned by `GetChartElement` .

Comment: Thanks @TinMan. Could not get clear about idea, how to avoid iteration for getting series point in case of OHLC chart. Please give some more hints in this regard. In exception to normal chart where series in a point or bar, in OHLC for finding series user have to point mouse to only extreme end points of Up/Down bars, High, Low Lines. Norma tendency of the user would be to point mouse anywhere within this bars. So reluctantly i comprise the performance by iterating for Y to get `xlSeries` corresponding to X.

Comment: Actually years back in my work place used similar technique to manipulate scatter/bar/ line chart to drag & pull series points to get maximum efficient operations etc. in these cases it is easy to find the series points with mouse. **But while trying with OHLC, I find that normal tendency of user would be to point anywhere within the bar.** So against normal code ethics I had to adapt to iteration for finding Y.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want Tooltips, or Data Labels?

A candlestick chart has Tooltips that appear when your mouse moves over any of the data points (high or low at the ends of the whiskers, open or close at the ends of the boxes).

Data Labels are permanent labels adjacent to a chart's data points. These are added by clicking the plus icon floating beside the chart and checking the box next to Data Labels, or finding the relevant command on the ribbon. I fear that data labels on every point will make the chart cluttered.